# Ionic serve unexpectedly closed on macOS X (npm issue)

Tags: macos, ionic-framework, npm

I installed npm ionic cordova on MacOS X 10.13

```
sudo npm install -g cordova ionic
```

Then I ran

```
ionic serve
```

and got an error suggesting to do :

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /Users/admin/.config
```

which I did.

And now I can't run `ionic serve`:

```
$ ionic serve
> ionic-v1 serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8100 --livereload-port=35729 --dev-port=53703 --engine=browser
[v1] ionic-v1[12966]: ../src/node_contextify.cc:627:static void node::contextify::ContextifyScript::New(const FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> &): Assertion `args[1]->IsString()' failed.
[v1]  1: 0x10003818c node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node]
[v1]  2: 0x100037367 node::MakeCallback(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Object>, char const*, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*, node::async_context) [/usr/local/bin/node]
[v1]  3: 0x10005c3de node::contextify::ContextifyScript::New(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) [/usr/local/bin/node]
[v1]  4: 0x1001f14e8 v8::internal::FunctionCallbackArguments::Call(v8::internal::CallHandlerInfo*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
[v1]  5: 0x1001f0811 v8::internal::MaybeHandle<v8::internal::Object> v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::HandleApiCallHelper<true>(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::FunctionTemplateInfo>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::BuiltinArguments) [/usr/local/bin/node]
[v1]  6: 0x1001f0270 v8::internal::Builtin_Impl_HandleApiCall(v8::internal::BuiltinArguments, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
[v1]  7: 0x256b62bdc01d 

[ERROR] A utility CLI has unexpectedly closed (exit code null).

        The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error 
        details.

$ npm i -D @ionic/v1-tookit
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @ionic/v1-tookit@latest

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/admin/.npm/_logs/2018-09-06T11_18_15_262Z-debug.log
```

Here is my info:

```
$ ionic info
[WARN] Bad integration name: gulp
✔ Gathering environment info - done!

Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.1.2 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.3.4
   @ionic/v1-toolkit : 1.0.8

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : none
   Cordova Plugins       : no whitelisted plugins (0 plugins total)

System:

   NodeJS : v10.9.0 (/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.9.0/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.2.0
   OS     : macOS High Sierra
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Did you try to re-install ionic and the ionic-cli?

Comment: thats exactly what I did, I uninstalled completely ionic cordova and node, reinstalled everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled cordova, ionic and node, and reinstalled them, including nvm.